# Issue in accessing user contacts in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am accessing user contacts in iOS.I have called a function which access the user contacts.An alert dialog is shown when this function is called & asking to user allow access to contacts or not.My code works fine if user allow the access.If user don't allow access then i want to again show that dialog of asking permission to user for accessing contacts.I am using following code for accessing the user contacts.Please tel me what to do.

code:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
{
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
        {
            NSLog(@"acess:first block");
            // First time access has been granted, add the contact
            access=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [access setObject:@"false" forKey:@"contact_access"];
            [access synchronize];
        });
 }
 else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
 {
            NSLog(@"acess:second block");
        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        access=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [access setObject:@"true" forKey:@"contact_access"];
        [access synchronize];
 }

 else
 {
        NSLog(@"acess:third block");
        // The user has previously denied access
        // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings appa
        access=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [access setObject:@"false" forKey:@"contact_access"];
        [access synchronize];
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Please allow access to contacts to use rolodex feature" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

 }
```

Comment: @Eugene,Jems answers are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to show the permission popup twice in an iOS application. It's the same strategy for Location, Calendar, Photos, etc.

The possibility you've got is:

- on iOS8 and later: Redirect the user on the application setting page, using the deep link provided by `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`

  ```
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
  ```
- **on previous iOS version**: Create a popup to warn the user that the application has no access to the contact list, and describe the way to grant access (Go to Setting-> Your App -> Contact ...)

Answer (score 1):

The "allow contacts access" alert that is being shown to user in your app is managed by the system. It's shown once when you **initially** request access to contacts, user can either permit or deny the access. This alert will never be shown again once user has made a choice. If contacts access has been denied once, the only way to permit access to the contacts then is to go to Settings app and enable access using a switch manually via Contacts section in Privacy tab.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly call this below code in your viewDidLoad method or wherever you want apply this below coding

```
  ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);

  if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
  {
      ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
      if (granted) {
        // If the app is authorized to access the first time then add the contact

      } 
      else 
      {
        // Show an alert here if user denies access telling that the contact cannot be added because you didn't allow it to access the contacts
      }
   });
  }
  else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) 
  {
    // If the user user has earlier provided the access, then add the contact

  }
  else 
  {
     // If the user user has NOT earlier provided the access, create an alert to tell the user to go to Settings app and allow access
  }
```